# What is the best way to resolve Node.js promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to call my native C++ function implemented with NAN(Native Abstraction for Node.js) with a Promise Asynchronous. Unfortunately the Promise is never resolved.
My Code in Javascript.

```
function callbackDoAsyncStuffFirst() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    module.doAsyncStuffFirst(function (error, a, v, b) {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      console.log("Resolve First: ", a, " ", b, " ", v, " ");
      let ret = [a, b, v];
      console.log("Return frist Resolve");
      return resolve(ret);
    });
  });
}

function callbackDoAsyncStuff() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    module.doAsyncStuffSecond(function (error, a, b) {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      console.log("Returned: ", a, " ", b);
      let ret = [a, b];
      console.log("Call Second Resolve");
      return resolve(ret);
    }, 'valueA', 'valueB');
  });
}

let p = callbackDoAsyncStuffFirst().then((retArray) => { console.log("resolve first-->", retArray) });

let second = callbackDoAsyncStuff().then((retArray) => { console.log("resolve second-->: ", retArray) });
```

The console output looks like

```
C++: Start Execute
C++: HandleOKCallback
JS: Resolve First:  a, b, v
JS: Return frist Resolve
```

After this nothing happens any more.

Comment: FYI:  [The example from the documentation is here](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/callback.md)

Comment: Thank you! I Used the AsyncWorker [AsyncWorker](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/asyncworker.md)

Comment: But all you're observing appears to be that `doAsyncStuffSecond` doesn't call its callback.  You could provide the code for `doAsyncStuffSecond` if you need help with what's going on inside it.

Comment: bevor ```callbackDoAsyncStuffFirst()``` has to be resolved ? or will it only resolve when the second promise is also finished?

Comment: are there any errors in the console? seems like there are syntax errors, missing params etc

Comment: No Errors at all. It just stops. a just should resolve to undefined

Comment: @RepoMan The promise chain captures the errors. Can you add `.catch(error => console.error(error))` at the end of each promise chain?

Comment: I added ```.catch(error => console.error(error))``` no errors are logged

Comment: @RepoMan Here 2nd one: `then((retArray) => { console.log("resolve second-->: ", a) });` What is `a`, shoud have been `retArray`.

Comment: You're currently also referencing `error` in the `doAsyncStuffSecond` callback while it is not defined at that point.

Comment: can it be that both Promises have to be finished before they can be resolved?

Comment: From the C++ output we can't see which method is actually called. Could you update both functions so we can see that the call actually hits the correct C++ function? (assuming the C++ is under your command)

Comment: I just added a ```setTimeout(()=>{}, 100); ```and now the promise ist resolved while the second is pending like expected. but why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fake module demonstrates that the problem is in your C++ plugin, not in your JavaScript, which works correctly here.

It also demonstrates how to call the callback with a "successful" set of arguments, in that the first callback argument you are interpreting as an error, which must be falsey in order for you not to reject your promise.

```js
var module = {
  doAsyncStuffFirst: (cb) => {
    cb(undefined, 'dummy_a1', 'dummy_v1', 'dummy_b1');
  },
  doAsyncStuffSecond: (cb) => {
    cb(undefined, 'dummy_a2', 'dummy_b2');
  }
}

function callbackDoAsyncStuffFirst() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    module.doAsyncStuffFirst(function (error, a, v, b) {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      console.log("Resolve First: ", a, " ", b, " ", v, " ");
      let ret = [a, b, v];
      console.log("Return frist Resolve");
      return resolve(ret);
    });
  });
}

function callbackDoAsyncStuff() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    module.doAsyncStuffSecond(function (error, a, b) {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      console.log("Returned: ", a, " ", b);
      let ret = [a, b];
      console.log("Call Second Resolve");
      return resolve(ret);
    }, 'valueA', 'valueB');
  });
}

let p = callbackDoAsyncStuffFirst().then((retArray) => { console.log("resolve first-->", retArray) });

let second = callbackDoAsyncStuff().then((retArray) => { console.log("resolve second-->: ", retArray) });
```